# how to make a selection in the list, and if you press it will open the details (Sencha Touch)

Tags: extjs, touch

how to make a selection in the list, and if you press it will open the edit (Sencha Touch).

This code calls the opening of the form

```
if (!this.editContact) {
       this.editContact = Ext.create('MM.view.contact.Edit');
        }
        this.editContact.setRecord(record);

        this.getMain().push(this.editContact);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add an `itemptap` listener 
http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.3.1/#!/api/Ext.dataview.List-event-itemtap

Record is the forth argument passed into the listener:
( this, index, target, **record**, e, eOpts )